# Sleep в нескольких потоках Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

Алгоритм прост: если левая кнопка мыши нажата, то через секунду зажимается клавиша. Если кнопка мыши отпущена, то через это же время клавиша отжимается.

Вот мой код (Если будете тестировать, то после завершения программы нужно прожать-отжать "ctrl"):

```
import keyboard
from pynput import mouse
import time
import threading

PressBut: int = 0


def thread_function():
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press("ctrl")
    print("ctrl press")


def thread_function_2():
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.release("ctrl")
    print("ctrl release")


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global PressBut
    if pressed:
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            print(button)
            PressBut = 1

    elif not pressed:
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            print(button)
            PressBut = 0

    print(PressBut)

    if PressBut:
        x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function())
        x.start()
    else:
        x2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function_2())
        x2.start()


with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Нормальный последовательный вывод:

```
Button.left
1
ctrl press
Button.left
0
ctrl release
```

Если не ждать секунду с зажатой кнопкой, то программа уходит в сон и не считывает события мыши:

```
Button.left
1
ctrl press
```

Ровно также и при отпускании: если после отпускания кнопки не ждать секунду, то считывания не будет.

Как сделать нормальную многопоточность, чтобы считывание мыши не уходило в сон во время отсчёта таймера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один вариант решения - это сохранять точное время когда случилось событие нажатия или отпускания мыши, тогда в потоке можно легко отследить в какой момен нажать или отпустить клавишу. Мой вариант кода ниже так и реализован.

Также не обязательно иметь два потока, удобней иметь один поток обрабатывающий клавиши. Этот поток ждёт 1 секунду момента, когда разница времени между последним нажатием клавиши и событием мыши будет достаточной, и тогда нажимает клавишу.

Для получения точного времени, дробное число секунд с компьютерной Эпохи (с даты `1970.01.01`), используется [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time), для создания паузы равной указанному дробному числу секунд используется [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep).

Также поток, обрабатывающий клавиши, желательно запускать всего один раз во время старта программы. Хотя также вполне возможно стартовать его и в момент событий мыши.

В вашем коде поток запускается как `threading.Thread(target = thread_function())`, здесь ошибка, правильно так `threading.Thread(target = thread_function)`, т.е. после `thread_function` не нужны скобки, это обязательно.

Также я заметил, что у меня на Windows 10 `pynput` начинает сильно тормозить скрипт если нажимать мышью внутри окна консоли, но отлично работает если нажимать на ободок окна, может у других этого нет. Это особенность модуля `pynput`, какой то баг. Этого не исправишь просто так, код обработки мыши полностью соответствует [документации](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html), поэтому это вина реализации модуля `pynput`.

Полный доработанный код:

```py
import keyboard
from pynput import mouse
import time
import threading

PressBut = (False, 0)

def thread_function():
    last = False
    while True:
        if PressBut[0] != last:
            while PressBut[0] != last and not (time.time() - PressBut[1] >= 1.0):
                time.sleep(0.05)
            if PressBut[0] != last:
                if PressBut[0]:
                    print("ctrl press")
                    keyboard.press("ctrl")
                else:
                    print("ctrl release")
                    keyboard.release("ctrl")
                last = PressBut[0]
        else:
            time.sleep(0.05)

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global PressBut
    
    if pressed:
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            print(button)
            PressBut = (True, time.time())
    elif not pressed:
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            print(button)
            PressBut = (False, time.time())

    print(PressBut)

t0 = threading.Thread(target = thread_function)
t0.start()

with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
    
print('Finished!')

t0.join()
```

Output:

```
Button.left
(True, 1638329281.1674185)
ctrl press
Button.left
(False, 1638329283.761459)
ctrl release
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за уделённое время. Главное, что клики сейчас считываются во время отсчёта(сравнивания времени) и с этим можно работать.